# Assemble two sql queries result that have nothing in common

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

How can I insert values into a table if these values are retrieved from two different tables that have nothing in common?
From the first table i will retrieve (SELECT) only one value and the remaining values will be retrieved from the second table.

I want to retrieve the first value from the first table and the remaining values from the second table and then return all these into the INSERT that i want to perform.

EDIT : Here an example of the structure :

Here are the tables.  I hope this is clear. Feel free to ask me for more details.

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(id int,  productName  varchar(7),  description  varchar(55))
;

CREATE TABLE table2
(id int,  productName  varchar(7))
;
```

This is what I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (`id`,`productName`)
SELECT COALESCE(Max(id + 1), 0) 
FROM table2 
UNION 
SELECT productName 
FROM table1
```

This will get me an error obviously but at least this is more clearer I hope.

Comment: You should perform some kind of join of two tables, and then insert a resultset. If you post tables strusture you wil get solution

Comment: So to be clear, for each value in the first table, you want every value from the second table and to insert the results? That is, if the first table has 10 values and the second table has 5 values, you want 50 results inserted?

Comment: Please refer to the new EDIT for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use an in-line view to get the maximum current ID of `Table2`.  Then CROSS JOIN that with `Table1` to generate a Cartesian product.  I think you need distinct IDs for the new records, so I suggest you increment the derived maximum ID for each row.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id,productName) 
SELECT  t2.max_id + rownum
       , t1.productName   
FROM ( select COALESCE(Max(t2.id), 0) as max_id 
       from table2 ) t2
     CROSS JOIN  table1 t1
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! I'll give it a try and let you know if it works !